# Order by Contains in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list known as **roles**. Using this list, I'm getting another list called **menu**, where in a an Entity field called RoleType to which I insert the d.RoleID too.

How can I order the second list by the **RoleType = d.RoleID** in the second list called menu?

I've tried `.Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(RoleType)`, but it doesn't work.

```
var roles = (from d in db.TB_UserRoles
              where d.UserID == userID
              select d.RoleID).ToList();


var menu = (from d in db.TB_MenuRoles
            where roles.Contains(d.RoleID)
            select new Menu
            {
             MenuName = d.TB_Menu.Name,
             RoleType = d.RoleID
            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy(RoleType)` is not a valid linq syntax, it should be

`OrderBy(x => x.RoleType)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
var roles = (from d in db.TB_UserRoles
              where d.UserID == userID
              select d.RoleID).ToList();


var menu = (from d in db.TB_MenuRoles
            where roles.Contains(d.RoleID)
            select new Menu
            {
             MenuName = d.TB_Menu.Name,
             RoleType = d.RoleID
            }).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x.RoleType).ToList();
```